# Anaconda Failed to create menus, 'ascii' can't decode when dlib installing

Tags: python, anaconda, dlib

Good afternoon, I have a problem with Anaconda, when I install it, I had this error:

```
Failed to create Anaconda menus.
```

I choose Skip button and finish installing process. But when I try to run conda.exe install -c menpo dlib=18.18 I have this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t decode byte 0xcd in position 15: ordinal not in range(128).
```

I try solve this problem with ways, that described on GitHub https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/732, also I try to install `dlib` with `pip`, build it from source, but all this ways didn't help me. Please, if somebody know ways to easy install `dlib` or solution for problem with my anaconda, help me.

Comment: Sorry to see that you have to struggle with installing anaconda. Because it's a way for us to avoid complexity of some installing. I encountered this several days before. And the reason is quite simple. Winxp is not supported any more. So when I switch from XP to win7 and higher. Everything got done. So if you are using the old system. Please consider an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use Win 7. I try to install Miniconda and Anaconda on my computer with Win 10, but it doesn't help me. But I will try to install Anaconda on my win server, maybe it will helps me.